# How do I implement exception Handling with while loops

Tags: c#

I want the the program to ask the user to enter the number again and again until the format exception is not there.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int userGuess1 = 0;
    int userGuess2 = 0;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game. To win User 2 must guess the number User 1 inputs!");
            Console.WriteLine("User 1, Guess a number between 1 and 10 : ");
            userGuess1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("User 2, Guess a number between 1 and 10 : ");
            userGuess2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (userGuess2 < userGuess1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low.");
            }
            else if (userGuess2 > userGuess1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high.");
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers between 1 and 10 only.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    while (userGuess1 != userGuess2);

    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You won!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I cant get the program to loop again. It exits when there is an format exception. I did try moving try and catch statements but it generates errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is to start with different values for `userGuess1` and `userGuess2`.

```
int userGuess1 = -1;
int userGuess2 = -2;
```

That's because your code exits the loop when those two variables are the same - so don't set them the same at the start of your program.

---

A better answer is to implement a method like this:

```
    int ReadInt32()
    {
        int value = 0;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value) || value < 1 || value > 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10 :");
        }
        return value;
    }
```

This will keep retrying the one input until you have success.

Now your main loop looks like this:

```
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game. To win User 2 must guess the number User 1 inputs!");
        Console.WriteLine("User 1, Guess a number between 1 and 10 : ");
        userGuess1 = ReadInt32();
        Console.WriteLine("User 2, Guess a number between 1 and 10 : ");
        userGuess2 = ReadInt32();

        if (userGuess2 < userGuess1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low.");
        }
        else if (userGuess2 > userGuess1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high.");
        }
    }
    while (userGuess1 != userGuess2);
```

Note that I removed the now redundant `try`/`catch`.

Comment: OP: I personally would then extend this solution by providing an option to cancel at any stage. But that is only "nice to have".

Comment: @Fildor - I would normally use an `int?` or a `Maybe<int>` to represent the result and exit on that if its `null` or `Nothing`.

Comment: Something like that, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-8.0). I've added two variables.

- `string userGuess` will get value from user input.
- `bool isValid` will get return value from `int.TryParse`. So, in case user has added invalid value then `isValid` will be `false`.

Additionally, I've added `do..while` loops so that it will ask to re-enter value until valid value is not provided. Also removed `try..catch` since they are not required anymore.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int userGuess1 = 0;
    int userGuess2 = 0;
    string userGuess;
    bool isValid;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game. To win User 2 must guess the number User 1 inputs!");
        
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User 1, Guess a number between 1 and 10 : ");
            userGuess = Console.ReadLine();
            isValid = int.TryParse(userGuess, out userGuess1);
            // Add any additional validations if required, like if isValid == true, then it should also check userGuess1 >= 1 && userGuess1 <= 10. If not then set isValid = false;
        }
        while (!isValid);
            
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User 2, Guess a number between 1 and 10 : ");
            userGuess = Console.ReadLine();
            isValid = int.TryParse(userGuess, out userGuess2);
        }
        while (!isValid);

        if (userGuess2 < userGuess1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low.");
        }
        else if (userGuess2 > userGuess1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high.");
        }
    }
    while (userGuess1 != userGuess2);

    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You won!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```